# Regex for RegularExpressionAttribute must contain "[S]" text

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a Regex pattern that matches text that contains "[S]". I'd tried something like this:

```
^(?\\[S\\]$)$
```

But it's not working.
How can I achieve this?

Edit:

The purpose of the regex is to use it as a regular expression in client side validation:

```
[RegularExpression("\\[S\\]", ErrorMessage = "The field must contain '[S]'.")]
```

But this is not working. Because is only valid when the field is "[S]".

Comment: Remove the anchors, it should be just `(?\\[S\\])`, if you anchor the regex to the beginning and end of the string only if the string is exactly `"[S]"` will match.

Comment: I tried `(?\\[S\\])` but that gives me an ArgumentException.

Comment: hmmm, it's because the "?", remove it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm need a Regex that match a text when this have the text "[S]".

Why use a regex to check for a literal? Use

```
if (str.Contains("[S]")) { ... }
```

If you need it as a part of a regex , use

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\[S\]")) ...
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you want to match a field *containing* an `[S]` **with a `RegularExpressionAttribute`**. The `RegularExpressionAttribute` *requires a full string match*.

Thus, you need

```
[RegularExpression(".*\\[S].*", ErrorMessage = "The field must contain '[S]'.")]
```

Note that you do not have to escape a `]` outside a character class, it is treated as a literal. The `.*` will match zero or more character other than a newline. If you need to also match a newline, you can either use `"(?s).*\\[S].*"` or `@"[\s\S]*\[S][\s\S]*"`.

Comment: I need regex because I'm going to use it as a regular expression. Sorry for  not mention that before.

Comment: Great, you have it, use `\[S]`. If you need the pattern to *match the full string*, just add anchors (`^` to make sure we start searching at the beginning of a string, and `$` to make sure we are at the end of the string): `@"^\[S]$"`. I forgot to mention that `]` does not have to be escaped.

Comment: @ajmena: Is your problem fixed now? I noticed that you want to match a field *containing* an `[S]`. The `RegularExpressionAttribute` requires a full string match. ?Thus, **you need `[RegularExpression(".*\\[S].*", ErrorMessage = "The field must contain '[S]'.")]`**.

Comment: It's solved now. Your last comment hit the nail on the head. Thank you very much.